# Notary cannot install Corda service

Tags: blockchain, corda, notary

I was trying to configure Business network Operator services in my solution by adding the [toolkit](https://github.com/corda/corda-solutions/tree/master/bn-apps/memberships-management) provided by r3 as corrdapp dependancy in my application.I am able to build the application but when I runnodes i am getting error for Notary

**UPDATE**

I am adding the log

```
    [ERROR] 2020-09-04T14:21:15,399Z [main] internal.Node. - Unable to install Corda service com.r3.businessnetworks.membership.flows.bno.service.BNOConfigurationService -  [errorCode=dfc7g6, moreInformationAt=https://errors.corda.net/OS/4.5/dfc7g6]
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_201]
    [...]
    at net.corda.node.Corda.main(Corda.kt:13) ~[corda-node-4.5.jar:?]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.r3.businessnetworks.membership.flows.ConfigUtils.loadConfig(ConfigUtils.kt:16) ~[?:?]
    at com.r3.businessnetworks.membership.flows.bno.service.BNOConfigurationService.<init>(BNOConfigurationService.kt:21) ~[?:?]
    ... 33 more
[ERROR] 2020-09-04T14:21:15,458Z [main] internal.NodeStartupLogging. - Exception during node startup -  [errorCode=dfc7g6, moreInformationAt=https://errors.corda.net/OS/4.5/dfc7g6]
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_201]
    [...]
    at net.corda.cliutils.CordaCliWrapperKt.start(CordaCliWrapper.kt:89) ~[corda-tools-cliutils-4.5.jar:?]
    at net.corda.node.Corda.main(Corda.kt:13) ~[corda-node-4.5.jar:?]
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.r3.businessnetworks.membership.flows.ConfigUtils.loadConfig(ConfigUtils.kt:16) ~[?:?]
    at com.r3.businessnetworks.membership.flows.bno.service.BNOConfigurationService.<init>(BNOConfigurationService.kt:21) ~[?:?]
    ... 33 more
```

Comment: Please update your question with more of the error stack; you can find the log file of your node inside the `logs` folder.

Comment: HI,I have added the log

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the configuration file of this CorDapp as explained [here](https://blog.b9lab.com/how-to-create-a-cordapp-configuration-file-ef79581b9e3-ef79581b9e3c); you must:

1. Create a  `config` folder inside your node's `cordapps` folder (i.e. `node-folder/cordapps/config`).
2. Inside that folder create a `membership-service.conf` file.
3. Inside that file add:

   ```
   // Whitelist of accepted BNOs. Attempt to communicate to not whitelisted 
   // BNO would result into an exception
   bnoWhitelist = ["O=BNO,L=New York,C=US", "O=BNO,L=London,C=GB"]

   // Name of the notary to use for BNO transactions such as membership approval
   notaryName = "O=Notary,L=Longon,C=GB"
   ```

The CorDapp that you're using relies on a configuration file (the above 3 steps create that file) and it causes the `NullPointerException` when it's missing. To understand more about CorDapp configuration files, read [my article](https://blog.b9lab.com/how-to-create-a-cordapp-configuration-file-ef79581b9e3-ef79581b9e3c).

On a side note, according to [this](https://github.com/corda/corda-solutions/tree/master/bn-apps/memberships-management#deprecation-warning); the CorDapp that you're using will be deprecated on 31 September 2020.

Comment: Yes.. `// Name of the Notary
notaryName =  "O=Notary,L=London,C=GB"
bnoWhitelist = ["O=BNO,L=Tokyo,C=JP"]

// Name of the contract to validate membership transactions with.
// Defaults to "net.corda.businessnetworks.membership.states.MembershipContract" if not specified
// membershipContractName = "com.app.MyMembershipContract"

// Name of the class that implements MembershipAutoAcceptor interface. Optional parameter. 
// membershipAutoAcceptor = "com.app.MyMembershipAutoAcceptor" ` still the same

Comment: Did you place the `membership-service.conf` inside the `your-node-folder/cordapps/config` folder then **restart the node**?

Comment: I deployed the nodes,then ran a script file which copy a membership-service.conf to the required directory then i started the node.

Comment: Can you browse to the configs folder and confirm that the file was copied there?

Comment: Yes it is there

Comment: My build is in the project root rather than in workflows.Is that a problem?

Comment: No it's not a problem.